# Expected private type

Tags: ada, ada95

I have a compile-error that states: "expected private type "Pekare" defined at line 3. found an access type".

this is the .ads code:

```
package Image_Handling is

   type Data_Access is private;
   
   type Image_Type is record
      X_Dim, Y_Dim : Integer;
      Data : Data_Access := null;
   end record;
   type RGB_Type is private;

functions...

private

   type RGB_Type is record
      R, G ,B : Natural;
      T : Boolean := False;
      end record;
   
   type Undim_Array is array(Positive range <>, Positive range <>) of RGB_Type;
   
   type Data_Access is access Undim_Array;
   
end Image_Handling;
```

Comment: Why not simply state that type Undim_Array is private? You can then state that type Pekare is access Undim_Array in the public part of the package specification.

Comment: @JimRogers tried it and got the compile error : "full view of "Undim_Array" not compatible with declaration at line 3. one is constrained, the other unconstrained". Thanks for the help!

Comment: The way to indicate that `Undim_Array` is going to be unconstrained is by saying `type Undim_Array (<>) is private;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `Data_Access` type is private and not known to be an access type in the visible ("public") part of the spec. Therefore, you cannot assign `null` to the `Data` field as this would presume the `Data` field to be of an access type. The typical solution is to use a *deferred constant*. Such a constant can be declared and used in the public part of the spec, but it's full definition (i.e. it's actual value) is deferred to the private part. Below an example:

**image_handling.ads**

```
package Image_Handling is

   type Data_Access is private;
   None : constant Data_Access;   --  Deferred constant.
   
   type Image_Type is record
      X_Dim, Y_Dim : Integer;
      Data         : Data_Access := None;
   end record;
   type RGB_Type is private;   
   
private

   type RGB_Type is record
      R, G ,B : Natural;
      T       : Boolean := False;
   end record;
   
   type Undim_Array is array(Positive range <>, Positive range <>) of RGB_Type;
   
   type Data_Access is access Undim_Array;
   None : constant Data_Access := null; 
   -- ^^^ At this point we know that Data_Access is an access type and
   --     provide a full definition of the constant that states it's value.
   
end Image_Handling;
```

Comment: Thank you!! This solved my problem! :)))